# how to pass Map or List<Object> as a parameter to JPA query

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I need to pass a map as input parameter of type <Sting,String> or List  into two JPA columns and get the result as List of records for all the entries in the map/list.

Something like this:

```
@Query(
      value =
          "SELECT e from #{#entityName} e where e.name = KEY(someMap) and e.relationName = VALUE(someMap)")
  List<Member> findByNameAndRelationNameIn(
          @Param("someMap") Map<String, String> someMap);
```

OR

```
@Query(
      value =
          "SELECT e from #{#entityName} e where e.name IN (:#{#dataSpaceMembers.?[name]}) and e.dataSpaceName IN (:#{#dataSpaceMembers.?[dataSpaceName]})")
  List<DataSpaceMember> findByNameAndDataSpaceIn(
      @Param("dataSpaceMembers") List<DataSpaceMember> dataSpaceMembers);
```

But the application doesn't run since this is not a valid jpa query.
I don't want to run single queries in loop, but looking for a single query which can give result as a list.

Comment: You seem to want an open ended or dynamic number of e.name/e.relationName pairs added to the query based on the map entries, which isn't possible with a static query string. You must do so yourself with a criteria query, processing the map into key/value pairs on your own. See https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-criteria-queries for help

Comment: @Chris I am not able to find criteria examples which are similar to my use case.
My requirement is that there are 2 columns that I need to filter from a table but I have list/map as the input (and I dont want to use a loop).

Not able to find criteria for the same. Can you please refer a doc/link if you're aware of any? Thank you.

Comment: You need a query that has "where (e.name = :name1 and e.relationName = :value1) or (e.name = :name2 and e.relationName = :value2).." for each map key/value pair. Nothing accepts a map and will write the loop for you - you must do it yourself dynamically, once you have the map and can know how many pairs are in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible using @Query notation, however, like Chris said in the comments, you can pretty quickly write some code to dynamically create this kind of statement using a criteria query.

I think the code you're looking for would be something like this, where the supplied Map is a set of key/value pairs with the key being `name` and the value being `relationName`.

```java
    EntityManager em;

    public List<Member> get(Map<String, String> map) {
        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Member> cq = cb.createQuery(Member.class);

        Root<Member> root = cq.from(Member.class);
        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : map.entrySet()) {
            Predicate a = cb.equal(root.get("name"), e.getKey());
            Predicate b = cb.equal(root.get("relationName"), e.getValue());
            predicates.add(cb.and(a, b));
        }

        cq.where(cb.or(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0])));
        return em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
    }
```

Thr query this produces should have a combination of AND and OR statements that you're desiring, ie

```sql
SELECT * FROM member WHERE ((name = ? AND relationName = ?) OR (name = ? AND relationName = ?) ... etc)
```

**Note:**

Since a `Map` can only contain a key once, you might consider using a `List<KeyValue<String, String>>` or `List<Pair<String, String>>` instead. Both KeyValue and Pair can be found in Apache commons libraries and I believe Spring also includes a Pair implementation. Or you can write your own.

Comment: For me easier solution would be to create object named MyData containing name, relationName and pass as argument List<MyData> instead of map