# How to mapping Map to query in Repository in Spring Data Jpa?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

How to mapping Map to query in Repository in Spring Data Jpa?

Below is my Generic Repository source.

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface GenericRepository<T, ID> extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {

     @Query("select t from #{#entityName} t " +
             "where t.queryParams.getKey = queryParmas.getValue")
     Page<T> findByQueryParams(HashMap<String, String> queryParams, Pageable pageable);
}
```

As follows, I want to receive queryParams as a parameter and map the key and value corresponding to queryParams to the where clause.

Since it is a GenericRepository, it cannot be implemented, and I want to put the contents of the Map in @Query.

I've been searching, but I can't find anything about it, so I don't know how to solve this problem.

If there is any way, please let me know.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use JPA criteria queries https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-criteria-queries

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
EntityManager em;

public List<Member> get(Map<String, String> map) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Member> cq = cb.createQuery(Member.class);

    Root<Member> root = cq.from(Member.class);
    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : map.entrySet()) {
        Predicate a = cb.equal(root.get("name"), e.getKey());
        Predicate b = cb.equal(root.get("relationName"), e.getValue());
        predicates.add(cb.and(a, b));
    }

    cq.where(cb.or(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0])));
    return em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
}
```

[how to pass Map or List as a parameter to JPA query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71484237/how-to-pass-map-or-listobject-as-a-parameter-to-jpa-query)

[How to Access EntityManager with Spring Data](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-entitymanager)

Answer (score -1):

You need Spring JPA dynamic query. I have prepared a small application that will meet your needs. I hope it will be useful.

[github: dynamic query](https://github.com/hcaglarr/dynamic-query)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).